# How to combine different row values into a single column in R

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes in R. The first one is a list of patients.

```
Patient 1
Patient 2
Patient 3
```

The second one is a list of procedures, and their costs, per patient.

```
Procedure 1 - Patient 1 - Cost
Procedure 2 - Patient 1 - Cost
Procedure 3 - Patient 1 - Cost
Procedure 1 - Patient 2 - Cost
Procedure 1 - Patient 3 - Cost
```

Etc.

I want to add the costs, per patients, into a new column in the first data frame (i.e, total expenditure per patient)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just need to aggregate and merge your data.

Here’s some example data

```
patient_df <- structure(list(patient_id = 1:3, gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
print(patient_df)

##   patient_id gender
## 1          1      M
## 2          2      F
## 3          3      M

procedure_df <- structure(list(procedure_id = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1), patient_id = c(1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 3), cost = c(10, 5, 12, 10, 5, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
print(procedure_df)

##   procedure_id patient_id cost
## 1            1          1   10
## 2            2          1    5
## 3            3          1   12
## 4            1          2   10
## 5            2          2    5
## 6            1          3   10
```

Let’s aggregate the procedure data

```
library(dplyr)

total_costs <- procedure_df %>%
               group_by(patient_id) %>%
               summarize(total_cost = sum(cost)) %>%
               ungroup()
print(total_costs)

## # A tibble: 3 x 2
##   patient_id total_cost
##        <dbl>      <dbl>
## 1          1         27
## 2          2         15
## 3          3         10
```

And then merge it to patient data

```
patient_costs <- left_join(patient_df, total_costs, by = "patient_id")
print(patient_costs)

##   patient_id gender total_cost
## 1          1      M         27
## 2          2      F         15
## 3          3      M         10
```